# Why do I get: "Entropy pool not available to seed RNG; using ad-hoc entropy sources." by using Laplacians Package?

Tags: random, julia, julia-1.x

I am trying to use a package (Laplacians: https://github.com/danspielman/Laplacians.jl) with Julia- v1.0.4. However, I get the following message(error) when I use it:

"Entropy pool not available to seed RNG; using ad-hoc entropy sources."

The package says that it works with Julia -v1.0.0 and I assume that it should be fine with v1.0.4 too (am I right?)

When I use the package with Julia v0.0.7, I don't get this message but I get some warnings that some functions should be replaced.

Comment: Cross-posted (and somewhat answered) at https://discourse.julialang.org/t/what-does-this-mean-entropy-pool-not-available-to-seed-rng-using-ad-hoc-entropy-sources/26432.  Many of the same folks are at both sites — please just pick one and stick with it.  Otherwise people end up duplicating effort.

Answer (score 0):

I have experienced the same issue. It is likely an issue with using a not initialized random generator. Without a reproducible example it is hard to check if the issue is caused by a missing call in the library or your code but you can always try to add the initialization in place close to the cause of the error.